# Getting "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')" Error. Even though the array is declared and imported

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, next.js

I am trying to map through an array and display names so I can eventually dynamically route to pages for each person. The array is coming back as undefined despite it being declared. So that is why .map is not working. But where am I going wrong here?

I have this code for an array
/lib/api

```
export async function getCastDetails() {
    const members = (
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "name one"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "name two"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "name three"
      }
    )
    return members;
  }
```

and I have this code to map through the array and display the names on a page

```
import { getCastDetails } from "@/lib/api";

export async function getStaticProps() {
    const castData = await getCastDetails();
    return {
        props: {
            castData,
        }
    }
}
const CastCarousel = ({ castData }) => {

    console.log(castData);
    return (
        <div>
            {castData.map(member => (
                <div
                    key={member.id}
                >
                    <a>{member.name}</a>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
    )
}

export default CastCarousel
```

I am then displaying  on my index page

EDIT:
I believe I need to pass castData through my  component on my index page, but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Here is what my index page looks like

```
import CastCarousel from "@/components/CastCarousel"

const Cast = () => {
    return (
        <main>
            <div className="flex flex-col justify-center items-center h-screen">
                <div>
                    <h1
                        className="text-6xl relative"
                    >Explore The Guys</h1>
                </div>
                <div className="">
                    <CastCarousel/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    )
}

export default Cast
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays use `[]` and not `()`. I your case this function should be:

```
export async function getCastDetails() {
    const members = [
      {
        id: "1",
        name: "name one"
      },
      {
        id: "2",
        name: "name two"
      },
      {
        id: "3",
        name: "name three"
      }
    ]
    return members;
}
```

otherwise what is happening is that `members` is assigned the last object in that enumeration (the one with id 3) and that's why you get the `.map` error because it is an object and not an array.

Comment: I haven't look at the rest of the code so you might need some extra fixes but this one is to start with

Comment: Very well spotted but that doesn't explain the error message. If `castData` is the last object, the error would be _"map is not a function"_

Comment: I agree, I just stopped there at reading the code. I don't have the energy to continue, sorry

Comment: Thanks, so much for your response. I did notice the bracket error and fixed that. But the error persists. The array is still coming back as undefined. Any idea why?

Comment: @FrancisSales it's almost 12:30 midnight here in Copenhagen so I will have to call it a day. Will check out fresh in the morning and if no-one helped you I will try to do so.